# Avg or Sum of each subset data of sliding widow

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can you please help me to sum, average or use a mathematical function on each subset of the data after window sliding as shown in the below code(subset slide)

```py
import more_itertools
list(more_itertools.windowed([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],n=3, step=3))

Out[119]:
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to return a list of the **sum** of each subset:

```
import more_itertools

print([sum(s) for s in more_itertools.windowed([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],n=3, step=3)))
```

Output:

```
[6, 15, 24, 33, 42]
```

---

---

---

To find the **average**:

```
import more_itertools

print([sum(s)/3 for s in more_itertools.windowed([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],n=3, step=3)))
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0]
```

**Here is how to put them in functions:**

```
def sumlist(lst,n=3,step=3):
    
    return [sum(s) for s in more_itertools.windowed(lst,n=n,step=step)]]

def avglist(lst,n=3,step=3):
    
    return [sum(s)/n for s in more_itertools.windowed(lst,n=n,step=step)]]
```

**Or, it can also be:**

```
def sumlist(lst,n=3,step=3):
    lst2 = []
    for s in more_itertools.windowed(lst,n=n,step=step):
        su = 0
        for n in s:
            su += n
        lst2.append(su)
    return lst2


def avglist(lst,n=3,step=3):  
    lst2 = []
    for s in more_itertools.windowed(lst,n=n,step=step):
        su = 0
        for n in s:
            su += n
        lst2.append(su/n)
    return lst2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, I am getting an error message with the code as below:          File "<ipython-input-132-746e5eb6dde3>", line 3
    print([sum(s) for in more_itertools.windowed([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],n=3, step=3))
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you so much your the best!, just want to know if I can use any other mathematical function in the code by creating a separate function? Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any another method to subset the dataset (sliding window). I am getting error when I try this method with my actual datasets that is huge.

Comment: I sorted that out. But I wanted to ask is there a way to calculate kurtosis and functions from scipy.stats in this function? to extract statistical figures from the each subset of the data? could you please help me on this please? I want the same thing but not mean or sum rather Kutosis, skeness and built functions.

Comment: How to get kurtosis on this iteration?

Comment: ```import statistics 
from more_itertools import windowed                                                                        
   for dfs in x,y,z:
    for i in windowed(dfs,  n = 350,step = 350):
        xmead = dfs.x(scipy.stats.median_absolute_deviation(i)) ```

Comment: ```--------------------------------------------------------------------------


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'x'   ````

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. Perhaps post a separate question so others can help?